# How can I create an Esper statement and set the subscriber atomically so that I do not miss any updates?

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

I have a multi-threaded program running a CEP using Esper. While events are already being sent through the engine I create a new statement and set a subscriber. Because the `createEPL` method automatically starts the statement, it is possible that I will miss an update triggered by the statement between when the statement is started and when my subscriber is set. Consider this example:

```
EPStatement myStatement = epService.getEPAdministrator().createEPL(myStatementString);
// another thread sends an event that triggers my statement which at this moment has no subscribers
myStatement.setSubscriber(MySubscriber.this);
// now my subscriber will get updates but it potentially missed some since the statement was created
```

I could create my own locks to deal with this issue but I was wondering if their is an alternative approach for simultaneously creating a statement and setting a subscriber provided by the Esper API? Or alternatively, is their a way to create the EPStatement without having it automatically started so that I can assign my subscriber and then start the statement manually?

Answer (score 0):

You need to obtain a lock and do the multiple deployment-related steps inside the lock.
In the documentation there is [atomic deploying](http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.3.0/reference-esper/html_single/index.html#apiruntime-deployment-atomic)

```
runtime.getRuntimeInstanceWideLock().writeLock().lock();
// Start atomic management unit. 
// Any events concurrently being processed by other threads must complete before the code completes obtaining the lock. 
// Any events sent in by other threads will await the release of the lock.
try {
  // Perform operations such as : 
  //   - deploy and/or undeploy multiple compiled modules  (deployment admin API)
  //   - set statement listeners and subscribers while deploying
  // There is no need to obtain this lock when deploying or undeploying a single module.
  // The lock is reentrant and can be safely taken multiple times by the same thread.
  // Make sure you use "try" and "finally" just like we have it here.
}
finally {
  // Complete atomic management unit. 
  // Any events sent in by other threads will now continue processing against the changed set of statements.
  runtime.getRuntimeInstanceWideLock().writeLock().unlock();
}
```

Comment: I'm working with an older version where the getRuntimeInstanceWideLock() method is not available. What was the previous way to accomplish this in older versions of Esper?